# can i waiting for the asynchronous steps done ,and then return?

Tags: node.js

i am new to nodejs,i wrote a function like this:

```
function getResult(){
    var result='';
    //do something asynchronous,like query datebase and assign result
    db.query(sql,function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err;
        result=res;
    })
    return result;
}
```

i run it

```
getResult();
```

but i can't get result. it seems to be the function return before the asynchronous steps .

can i waiting for the asynchronous steps done,and then let the function return ?how?
thanks..

Comment: research callbacks...

Comment: You can't wait for asynchronous commands to finish. You can only subscribe to their completion. A good write-up using Ajax for the example is "[How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)" But, you'll want to define `getResult()` to either accept its own `callback` to be called or return something like a `Promise` that can be resolved when `res` is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's an easy issue, but it contains an important concept in node.js. let's look at this:
your code :

```
  function getResult(){
    var result='';
    //do something asynchronous,like query datebase and assign result
    db.query(sql,function(err,res){
      if(err) throw err;
       result=res;
    })
    return result;
  }
```

it runs like this: firstly, do

```
db.query (sql)
```

then, it may do

```
return result
```

directly. 
because when  the  query operation is done, it will do

```
function(err, res){ ...}
```

so, you may get the answer you want, may not.
how to fix this? you can use callback like this:

```
function getResult(callback){
  db.query (sql, function(err, res){
     if (err) throw err;
     callback res;
  });
}  

getResult(function(result){ 'do something you like with result' });
```

may it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

by using callbacks. This is one of the core concepts of javascript.

```
function getResult(callback){
    var result='';
    //do something asynchronous,like query datebase and assign result
    db.query(sql,function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(res);
    })
}
```

use this function with

```
getResult(function(res){
// do something
});
```